# A Method For Calculating Large Exponents Quickly

Tags: proof-verification, logarithms, hyperbolic-functions

I've derived a formula for calculating large exponents quickly:
$$a^b = 2 \cosh( - b \log( a ) )$$

My question is:  Has anyone seen anything similar?  I am curious if either it's novel OR if I have made an error. :)

My original post here:
http://forirony.tumblr.com/post/94189380146/a-different-way-to-calculate-large-exponentials

Comment: Please make your question self-contained by including all necessary material here, instead of linking to something that might disappear in the future.

Comment: (even thought the formula is not exact) I don't see that the 'quickly' here: $\cosh(x) \equiv (e^{x}+e^{-x})/2$. So you need to calculate 1 logarithm, 2 exponentials and 2 products to get $a^b$ which is much easier found by calculating just 1 exponential!

Comment: @albert I guess you didn't notice in your blog post that there's a difference between "1282529^1282529" and "1282529^1282529."

Comment: btw the reason you cannot solve "1282529^1282529" in time in Wolfram Alpha is that Wolfram Alpha tries to do it exactly since you input integers. If you instead type 'solve x=1282529.0^1282529' , i.e. with a floating point number then it gives you the answer straight away (and much faster than with your method).

Comment: An even faster formula would be $\exp(b\log a)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula is incorrect, but approximately correct for large b. The actual value of your expression is $$a^b+a^{-b}$$

You are mimicking the expression $$a^b = \exp(b\log a)$$ which is exact. Note that $\cosh x =(e^x +e^{-x})/2$; that's why your formula is close.

I'm not sure why you would want to use $\cosh$ instead of $\exp$ since it is inaccurate and typically more expensive to compute.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  I didn't know about the a^b=exp(b log a) formula!

Comment: Glad to help. You should *definitely* know that identity--it essentially defines logarithms. Note too that your formula could use $\sinh$ just as well, for the same reason, but it would still be only an approximation.

Answer (score 3):

We note that by the definition:

$$\cosh(x)\equiv \frac{1}{2}(e^{z}+e^{-z})$$

We have that:

$$2\cosh(-b\log(a))=e^{b\log(a)}+e^{-b\log(a)}=a^{b}+a^{-b}$$

So, whilst your formula is very close for $a,b$ such that $a^{-b}\ll a^{b}$, it is not exactly an identity.

Comment: Indeed, this analysis shows that it is *never* correct unless $a=0$, and even that case blows up the $\log a$ term.